# Array in foreach loop string returning entire instead of single variable

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-installer

I'm creating an array like so

```
$softwareguid = get-wmiobject -class Win32_Product | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Name -like "ESET*"};
```

And then iterating through to perform an msiexec silent remove, however having trouble constructing the variable(s) to perform `invoke-expression`.

Code:

```
foreach ($remove in $softwareguid){ $uninstallcmd = "Detected"$remove.Name"with GUID"$remove.IdentifyingNumber;}
```

Results in the following errors:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your string interpolation in a **subexpression** `$()`:

```
$uninstallcmd = "Detected $($remove.Name) with GUID $($remove.IdentifyingNumber)";
```